# Eager Loading of Relation data in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-widgets

I am using a form that has a relation field inside. Although this is fine when few items are in the relation it gets quite slow when there are a lot. I wish to eager load some of the relationships to improve response times but I find it hard to find where I can access the query builder before it is run.

If I were using a standard list view I would go about doing this by extending the list query as below:

```
public function listExtendQuery($query)
{
    $query->with(['photos'])
}
```

But I have no idea how I can perform the exact same thing when loading the list using the relation widget. I have gone through the documentation multiple times but I did not manage to get this working.

Can anyone assist on this?

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe if we told you that [formExtendQuery method](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#extend-model-query) is a thing? :)

```
public function formExtendQuery($query)
{
    $query->with(['photos']);
}
```

Comment: I actually would, cause I've already tried that :)

It does not seem to have any effect on the relation field (not to be confused with database/model relationships).

Comment: Ah. Did you check with debug toolbar or some other way? There's also relationExtendViewWidget method with (parent) $model parameter, maybe it could be useful?